# How do i check if the user didn't enter anything from the keyboard?

Tags: c, user-input

I'm trying to write a program that would prompt the user for any integer input,but i don't know how to check if the user didn't input anything,I need some help with this please.

As for my code I'm not sure if this warrants posting any because it would just be a scanf function.

Comment: What do you mean about "didn't input anything"? Is it after the user press enter or if the user doesn't press anything at all?

Comment: Yeah I meant after the user pressed enter,I don't think there's a way to check if the user didn't enter anything before pressing enter anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your input method.

1. `fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin)`

   If the user did not input anything, `buffer[0]` will be `'\n'`.
2. `int succeededCount = scanf(" %d", &dest)`

   If `scanf` could not populate `dest` from the user input (i.e. because it was empty or invalid), its return value in `succeededCount` will be `0` instead of `1`, because `scanf`'s return value is the number of items it successfully populated.

Comment: Thanks,but how can I check if the user only entered the newline character with scanf?I only want the user to enter integers ,when I tried what you wrote it worked when the user entered a character but not when the user pressed the newline character, ie he didn't enter anything.